# Horizontal scroll with dynamic item width in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-recyclerview

I need to create a scrolling effect, which expands the space between items if an item is less than some defined width (for portraits). That is done so that the amount of previous/next items shown is always the same once the centre item is centred.

I have implemented that by adding a scroll listener to the recycler view, in which I change the width of all partially or fully visible items if they are portraits. The minimal spacing between items is done by setting left and right margins on items, and that does not change between items, except for the first and last one, which have a bigger margin on the side that's by the end so that they remain centred.

The implementation below works nicely if I scroll slowly, but when I fling, it creates a jittery motion. I'm guessing it's because the fling calculates the number of pixels it needs to scroll based on the width of the object at the time of the fling... but because of the width changes, the fling motion calculation is wrong, so it needs to adjust, which I'm guessing creates the jitter, the problem is that I don't know how to fix it.

This is how the slow scroll looks like (working nicely):

[image: Scrolling Gif]

And the jittery fling:

[image: Flinging Gif]

The code used (I skipped over parts that I think don't change anything):
in MainActivity onCreate:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setInitialPrefetchItemCount(5);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), thumbnails, recyclerView, 8, 24);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

MyAdapter:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Thumbnail> galleryList, final RecyclerView recyclerView, float spacingDp, float sideItemsVisibleDp) {
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
    this.context = context;
    this.spacingDp = spacingDp;
    this.sideItemsVisibleDp = sideItemsVisibleDp;

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            if (layoutManager != null && windowWidth != 0) {
                int firstPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int lastPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (firstPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || lastPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Log.e(TAG, String.format(Locale.US, "onScrolled firstPosition %d lastPosition %d", firstPosition, lastPosition));
                    return;
                }

                for (int pos = firstPosition; pos <= lastPosition; pos++) {
                    View child = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(pos);
                    if (child != null) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(child);
                        viewHolder.computeAndSetWidth();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, String.format(Locale.US, "onScrolled pos %d child == null", pos));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, String.format(Locale.US, "onScrolled layoutManager %s windowWidth %d", layoutManager, windowWidth));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder position " + position);

    // Set the text of the position
    viewHolder.text.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", position));

    // Reset the container
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewHolder.container.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = itemMaxHeight;
    layoutParams.width = itemMaxWidth;
    viewHolder.container.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // Set the image
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource(galleryList.get(position).getImageId());

    int startEndSpace = (windowWidth - itemMaxWidth) / 2;
    int leftSpace = itemMinSpacing;
    int rightSpace = itemMinSpacing;

    if (position == 0) {    // leftmost
        leftSpace = startEndSpace;
    }
    if (position == (galleryList.size() - 1)) { // rightmost
        rightSpace = startEndSpace;
    }

    ((RecyclerView.LayoutParams) layoutParams).setMargins(leftSpace, 0, rightSpace, 0);
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View container;
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView text;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        container = view;
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    }

    public boolean isPortrait() {
        return img.getMeasuredHeight() > img.getMeasuredWidth();
    }


    public void computeAndSetWidth() {
        int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
        container.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);

        int imgWidth = img.getMeasuredWidth();
        int centerX = locationOnScreen[0] + container.getWidth() / 2;    // location on screen of the center of image on X axis
        float percentFromEdge;

        if (centerX == (windowWidth/2)) {
            percentFromEdge = 1.0f; // is in center
        } else if (centerX > 0 && centerX < (windowWidth/2)) {    // left side of screen, but center is on screen
            percentFromEdge = (2f*centerX) / windowWidth;
        } else if (centerX > (windowWidth/2) && centerX < windowWidth) {
            percentFromEdge =  2f * (windowWidth - centerX) / windowWidth;
        } else {    // off screen
            percentFromEdge = 0.0f;
        }

        int width = (int) ((itemMaxWidth - imgWidth) * percentFromEdge + imgWidth);

        setWidth(width);

    }


    private void setWidth(final int width) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = container.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = width;
        layoutParams.height = itemMaxHeight;
        container.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

}
```

cell_layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

RecyclerView is extended, where I override the fling to slow it down, but that's it:

```
@Override
public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
    return super.fling((int)(velocityX * flingFactor), (int)(velocityY * flingFactor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone with the same problem, this was my solution:

I made all the recyclerView items the same width, which was the max width allowed. I moved the ImageView within the item container left/center/right so that it was in center when the container was in the center, to the left of the container when the container was on the right and vice versa for the left side. This calculation was done instead of the call to viewHolder.computeAndSetWidth(); in recyclerView.OnScrollListener().

The last thing was to add a LinearSmoothScroller to my extended recyclerView  like this:

```
smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
            @Override
            protected int getHorizontalSnapPreference() {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_ANY;
            }

            @Override
            protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                return scrollMillisecondsPerInch / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
            }
        };
```